# NSMutableDictionary value lookup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

What is a good way of looking through a NSMutableDictionary to see if there is a key that corresponds to another variable?

Lets say i have a NSString "test"
and a mutable dictionary that has some values and NSString keys for those values.

What would be a good way of reading through the dictionary values to see if any of its keys are "test".

Would i have to have a for loop to read through dictionary values or is there something already a part of NSDictionary object that will do this that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:` method to find all keys where the value equals `@"test"`.

In the implementation below only the first key will be found. If you need all keys where the object is `@"Test"`, do not assign `*stop`.

```
NSString *target = @"test";
NSSet *keys = [myDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return (*stop = [target isEqual:obj]);
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is just the one whose key is exactly "test", I think you can just use [objectForKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey%3a) to try to get the corresponding object. If the key doesn't exist, the returned object will be nil.